# How to find config file for a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using HTML Validator, a Firefox plugin (available here: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/html-validator/)

But I've made a custom configuration (hiding some properties, etc.) and I want to share my configuration.

I don't know how I can extract this config file. Does anybody know where it is saved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't use that particular add-on, but based on [this (especially point 17)](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/faq.html), I guess the add-on's settings are stored as `about:config` preferences, with the names starting with `tidy.`.

If you're not familiar, `about:config` is the URL in Firefox which displays all (or almost all) the configuration settings of the browser.